# The argument type 'UserListModal?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserListModal'

Tags: flutter, dart

get error in return **userList![index]**

```
List<UserListModal?>? userList = [];
```

````
                  itemCount: userList!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return UserListView(user:userList![index]);
                  }))),```
````

Comment: I recommend you to learn more about null safety in dart https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 1):

Done it's front and back both two sides null safety

My SDK Version is Flutter 3.7.0-1.4

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: userList!.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return  UserListView(user:userList![index]!);
              }))),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your business logic, is it possible that userList can have null elements? Like:- userList = [null, null, UserListModal, null,]

If not, then please change the declaration to this:-

```
final List<UserListModal> userList = []
```

Explanation: Since you are assigning an empty list this this variable, userList cannot be null. So you can change the List<UserListModal?>? to List<UserListModal?>. And if you are not adding any null elements to this list, you can remove the remaining "?" i.e. change List<UserListModal?> to List.

I think you should read up on [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) in detail.

And using "final" makes sure that userModal cannot be re-assigned. This is a best practice for operating with lists.

Comment: get this **'userList' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'userList' non-final**.